# How do I select a value in a dropdown inside a table?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, html-table, row, dropdown

If I have a table with multiple rows, and each row has the same select box, how would I get the value of the selected dropdown? I'm currently only getting the first value in the first row no matter what row I pick.

```
 <form action="<?php echo $_POST['PHP_SELF'] ; ?>" method="post">
        <table class="radius" id="drTable">
            <tr>
                <th><a href="index.php?page=donation-requests&amp;order_by=a.dr_id&amp;order_direction=<?php if($order_direction == "ASC") { echo "DESC" ; } else { echo "ASC" ; } ?>">ID</a></th>
                <th><a href="index.php?page=donation-requests&amp;order_by=a.lastname&amp;order_direction=<?php if($order_direction == "ASC") { echo "DESC" ; } else { echo "ASC" ; } ?>">Name</a></th>                    
                <th><a href="index.php?page=donation-requests&amp;order_by=d.location&amp;order_direction=<?php if($order_direction == "ASC") { echo "DESC" ; } else { echo "ASC" ; } ?>">Store</a></th>
                <th><a href="index.php?page=donation-requests&amp;order_by=a.organization&amp;order_direction=<?php if($order_direction == "ASC") { echo "DESC" ; } else { echo "ASC" ; } ?>">Organization</a></th>
                <th><a href="index.php?page=donation-requests&amp;order_by=a.event_name&amp;order_direction=<?php if($order_direction == "ASC") { echo "DESC" ; } else { echo "ASC" ; } ?>">Event Name</a></th>
                <th><a href="index.php?page=donation-requests&amp;order_by=a.event_date&amp;order_direction=<?php if($order_direction == "ASC") { echo "DESC" ; } else { echo "ASC" ; } ?>">Event Date</a></th>
                <th><a href="index.php?page=donation-requests&amp;order_by=a.date_required&amp;order_direction=<?php if($order_direction == "ASC") { echo "DESC" ; } else { echo "ASC" ; } ?>">Date Needed By</a></th>
                <th><a href="index.php?page=donation-requests&amp;order_by=a.date_requested&amp;order_direction=<?php if($order_direction == "ASC") { echo "DESC" ; } else { echo "ASC" ; } ?>">Date Requested</a></th>
                <th><a href="index.php?page=donation-requests&amp;order_by=c.status&amp;order_direction=<?php if($order_direction == "ASC") { echo "DESC" ; } else { echo "ASC" ; } ?>">Status</a></th>
                  <th class="text-center">View/Edit</th>
                <th class="text-center">Delete</th> 
            </tr>
    <?php
            while($row = $result->fetch()) {
    ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['dr_id'] ; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['lastname'].", ".$row['firstname'] ; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['location'] ; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['organization'] ; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['event_name'] ; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo date("F j, Y", $row['event_date']) ; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo date("F j, Y", $row['date_required']) ; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo date("F j, Y", $row['date_requested']) ; ?></td>
                <td> 
                <select  class="radius" onchange="updateStatus(<?php echo $row['dr_id']; ?>);">
                    <option selected="true" disabled="disabled"><?php echo $row['status'];?></option>
                    <?php echo statusOptions($row['status']) ; ?>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class="text-center"> <a href="index.php?page=donation-requests-edit&amp;viewing_id=<?php echo $row['dr_id'] ; ?>&status=<?php echo $_GET['status'] ; ?>"><i class="fi-pencil size-24"></i></a></td>
                <td class="text-center"><a href="#" onClick="deleteRequest(<?php echo $row['dr_id'] ; ?>)"><i class="fi-trash size-24"></i></a></td> 
            </tr>                                   

    <?php               
            }       
    ?>              
        </table>
    </form>
```

jquery:

```
function updateStatus(dr_id) {

var id = dr_id;


  $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
    type: "GET",
    // url: "drStatus_update.php?id="+id+"&status="+status,         
    dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
    success: function(response){                    
        //alert(response);
        alert(status);
    }

    });

}
```

Comment: We need some of your code sample at least to know where the issue is.

Comment: Use [`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider you have below table markup

```
        <table id="tblData">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <option value="11">11</option>
                        <option value="12">12</option>
                    </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <option value="21">21</option>
                        <option value="22">22</option>
                    </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <option value="31">31</option>
                        <option value="32">32</option>
                    </select></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select>
                        <option value="41">41</option>
                        <option value="42" selected="selected">42</option>
                    </select></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

You can loop through each row and find the selected value.

```
       // loop through each row.
       $("#tblData tr").each(function () {
            // find the select tag and get its selected value.
            $(this).find("select").val();
        });
```

This way you can further achieve your functionality, above code shows how to target different dropdown in separate row.

Comment: Thank you - somehow it's giving me a blank result. I provided my code above in my question if that helps.

Comment: Can you include complete table in the code? And the functionality you want to achieve with the selected value or where you need to fetch the selected value.  Also I have seen disabled="disabled" attribute in the code, disabled item will not be rendered as option even if it is  selected="true" in your mark up. I hope you already know this.

Comment: I've just updated the code now to show the full table (above)

Comment: you can update your updateStatus function to include the element itself. like <select onchange="updateStatus(this);"> now you can use that function updateStatus(element)
        {
            var selectedvalue = $(element).val();
        }  . This way selectedvalue will contain that elements selected value from that particular row. You can include that element as second parameter as well, as you already have one parameter for your function.

Comment: Yes, I need it to grab two values. One is the id of the row which I put in the onchange function .. updateStatus((<?php echo $row['dr_id']; ?>);

Comment: I also need to be able to select the value of the dropdown in that same row, and display what value it is.

Comment: i found this: var status = $(this).closest('tr').find('#statusBox').val();

but it's giving me undefined

Comment: i tried this: var status = $('#statusBox option:selected').val();
and it just returns the first row only. What if I'm clicking on a drop down in the 5th row of the table, how do I get that specific value?

Comment: You can update your function call onchange="updateStatus((<?php echo $row['dr_id']; ?>, this);" (notice 2nd parameter here). Now when dropdown value is changed you can easily retrieve that value in updateStatus function itself as function updateStatus(dr_id, element) {
 var selectedvalue = $(element).val();
} . When you will change dropdown value in any of the row, this function will be called and you will find that selected value in this function with the  help of $(element).val();. Correct me if you want selected value of dropdown somewhere other than in the function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116815/discussion-between-mike-cerveni-and-dinesh-prajapati).

Answer (score 3):

I hope i understand you right!

**Checkout this:**

```js
// true: test onChange, false: use jQuery Event
var testOnChange = true; 


var $selectboxes = $('table').find('select');
$selectboxes.on('change', function() {
   if(testOnChange) {
     return;
   }
  
   var $select = $(this);
   var selectedText = $select.find('option:selected').text();
   var selectedValue = $select.val();
   $select.parent().next('td').html('Oh ' + selectedText + ', ' + selectedValue + '!!!' + '<br>Index: ' + $selectboxes.index(this));
});


function updateStatus(element) {
 
   if(!testOnChange) {
     return;
   }
  
   var $select = $(element);
   $select.parent().next('td').html(element.value + ' <br> ' + element.innerHTML + '<br> Index: ' + $selectboxes.index($select));
}
```

```css
table, td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <th>What i need?</th>
  <th>Really?</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <select onChange="updateStatus(this)">
      <option value="yes">Bier</option>
      <option value="yes">V(W)odka</option>
      <option value="no">Water</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <select onChange="updateStatus(this)">
      <option value="yes">McDonalds</option>
      <option value="yes">Burger King</option>
      <option value="no">Fish</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <select onChange="updateStatus(this)">
      <option value="no">-500$</option>
      <option value="yes">1.000.000$</option>
      <option value="yes">500$</option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td></td>
</tr>  
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you @pleinx. My select tag has an onchange function already. How do I loop through each select box in each row to find the selected value? Say there is 20 rows, and i click on the 5th row, I want to know what select box value is picked..

Comment: i already have an onchange on the select box as well: onchange="updateStatus(<?php echo $row['dr_id']; ?>)

Comment: i added also the case if you will your onChange function :)